# Android Emulator showing on left top corner

Tags: android, emulation

I have created emulator and launched it, first time is shows properly in center but after editing emulator size, It is showing on left top corner of monitor.
Unable to change position of emulator.

Before two days, My colleague also got same issue. We have same laptop which are HP EliteBook 8460P

Please find attached screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the icon in the taskbar, click move, then push the down arrow key on your keyboard.

Also, there is a windows program called Alt-Drag that lets you click anywhere on a window while holding the Alt key to move it. [You can find it here](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the emulator, than press Alt+Space, choose Move and then move the window with arrow keys or mouse. Or better yet, get the [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. This is a known bug with the default emulator.